# 'inout String' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<String>'

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I am using a function that takes an `UnsafePointer<String>`.

How do I get an `UnsafePointer<String>` from a String?

Trying `&someString` gives me the error:

```
'inout String' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<String>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&someString` creates a `CMutablePointer<String>`.

To convert it to an `UnsafePointer`, the simplest solution is to call the special function:

```
withUnsafePointer(&someString) { unsafePointer in
    //do something with the unsafePointer
}
```

Comment: Strangely, now this produces `Error:(26, 27) 'String' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T4'` if the String is a constant, or `Error:(26, 9) cannot convert the expression's type '(inout String, (($T6) -> ($T6) -> $T5) -> (($T6) -> $T5) -> $T5)' to type "Result"` if it's a variable